# Why can't I vectorize Python's datetime.utcfromtimestamp()?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I have an array of Unix timestamps.  I can run `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` on each entry individually, but I cannot run them all from a `numpy` array.  Why does that happen?

MWE

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

times = np.array((1524967210, 1524967211, 1524967212))

# Works
for i in times:
    print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(times[i]))

# Does not work
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(times[:]))
```

The second example issues: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` rather than an array of times.  A Unix timestamp conversion *seems* straightforward to implement as a vectorized operation ([see source code here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5527688aae11d0b5af58176267a9943576e71e5/Lib/datetime.py#L1637)), so why does it not work here?  Is there something I can do to alter this which will enable vectorized operation?

Comment: in case you're looking to work with numpy datetime, `times.astype('datetime64[s]')` should do the trick

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for the suggestion.  That is my usual method, but the modules I am working with downstream of the problem posed by this question require the official ``datetime`` input.  But if other folks come to this post with similar problems, your suggestion might help them.

Comment: adding `.tolist()` actually gives you just that, native Python datetime.datetime objects - or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Ah, that's new to me.  The one-liner ``times.astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()`` does indeed give a list of correct datetime objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.vectorize()` to create a vecorized version of the function which does what you want:

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

times = np.array((1524967210, 1524967211, 1524967212))
func = np.vectorize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

print(func(times[:]))
# or
print(func(times))
```

Comment: while more convenient than an list comprehension, it isn't faster

Comment: @hpaulj well, OP seemed pretty clear about what they wanted and didn't talk about list comprehension, did they?

Comment: @hpaulj also... [seems faster to me](https://tio.run/##jVDLigMhELz7FX1TYQgJy14C8yXLHszoJML4QNtAEvLts61mwl4W1kM3ZXVVtcYbXoL/WFfrYkgIvrh4A5XBRzan4ACtMxbhRXfUGa3QVLxxG2as1gwjeeyS8jq41qxHsR/gsDeftdKRbC5@6oNXM2FI9m7E5rMrONWg5obKRcl0oeE/ecZiqiG8P@LtCABHPrx2F7xmiiaSdEuzJ5NG2meA8xJOasnjgzeaH5smD9A0BGt7SrnlLDYjTMHFZC7GZxv875wvXQRKmEMC@j/fvb7/HakLAV0obl1/AA).

Comment: @hpaulj is correct in observing that this is slower than iteration for small inputs.  I did a quickie test and it looks to be ~3x slower.  Still, this is a good answer because I learned something, even if it isn't perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: @WesH interesting, my link above seems to suggest otherwise. List comprehension seems slower for me. How did you test that? If you are just focusing on a very small array of 3 values and not doing multiple iterations of the same test, that isn't a very meaningful test.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I edited my comment.  I observed that the time to vectorize + the operation is longer for small input sets.

Comment: @WesH ah, that makes sense! Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

`times` is a Numpy array of the `numpy` module and `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` is a function of the `datetime` module. `datetime` does not support Numpy array and it does not actually have any dependency with Numpy. In fact, because `datetime` is a [built-in module] of Python 3, having a dependency with Numpy would result in Numpy being a built-in module too! Numpy is an independent module developped by different people and there is no plan to add it in built-in modules yet. While `np.vectorize` could be used, it does not truly vectorise a function (it inefficiently calls the CPython function using a loop internally). It is provided for convenience and not speed.

The standard way to manipulate date/time in Numpy is using the [datetime64 type](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

Comment: This is really insightful.  I guess the gap in my knowledge is how ``numpy`` actually vectorizes.

Comment: numpy even follows a different philosophy with its datetime type compared to the Python built-in (UTC by default, no representation of date only etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.astype('datetime64[s]')`, then `.tolist()` to achieve the same result (a list of Python datetime objects, naive but representing UTC). A little `%timeit` comparison:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
func = np.vectorize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

N = 1000000
times = np.linspace(1524967210, 1524967210+N, N)

%timeit times.astype('datetime64[s]')
809 µs ± 26.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit times.astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()
56.4 ms ± 57.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit func(times)
174 ms ± 2.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t) for t in times]
311 ms ± 2.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Good answer.  It doesn't help me due to downstream complications, but it might help someone later.